# Python Code formatting the data when extracting the data from SQL and pasting it in excel file

Tags: python, sql-server, excel

My python code is establishing the database connection and executing a SQL Query to fetch some millions of records. Now after the logic is applied to the table few of the columns are extracted. Based on the difference in values the associated Primary Key is extracted.

Now Primary key when we query and check in SQL Developer window is something like "ABCAASASJDK2322-12-01". When the data is extracted and printed to see what value got pulled in, we can see the Primary Key value got modified to "ABCAASASJDK2322-Dec-01".

Now this is disturbing the solution as, the expected Primary key will never be found at the SQL developer window. There exists no record with Primary key as "ABCAASASJDK2322-Dec-01" when we query from SQL window.

Is there a way to stop Python doing this auto-formatting here?

My data is eventually going to get copied to an excel file, but when I am printing the execution result from file at cmd prompt I can clearly see the difference there itself.

Please help.

Code looks somewhat like below:

```py
import *****

#connection1
cursor.execute(query)
df1=pd.read_sql(query,connection)
df1.to_excel('File1.xls')

#connection2
cursor.execute(query)
df2=pd.read_sql(query,connection)
df2.to_excel('File2.xls')

df_comp = df1.compare(df2, keep_equal=True)
df_comp.to_excel('ComprReport.xls')

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('File1.xls')
worksheet1=wb1.active

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('ComprReport.xls')
worksheet = wb.active
newcolindex = int(worksheet.max_column) + 1
worksheet.insert_cols(idx=newcolindex)

worksheet.cell(row=2, col = newcolindex).value = 'KEY'
rowcounter = df_comp.shape[0]
uniquerec = int(rowcounter)
uniquerecrange = uniquerec  + 4

for x in range (4,diffrecrange)
#print(x)
    df1index = worksheet.cell(x,1)
    df1index = int(df1index.value)
    df1indexval = df1["PK"].iloc[df1index]
    #below line displays the value with numbers changed to date
    print(df1indexval)
    worksheet.cell(row=x, col=newcolindex).value=df1indexval

wb.save('ComprReport.xls')

cursor.close
```

Basically, after the dataframes are compared, the keys for the specific record is searched in the File1 and then wriitten back into the new column inside the comparison report.xl.

Please see if you can help on this anyway.

Thanks !!!

Comment: Neither SQL Server nor Python modify data. Only the application code does. Python would never produce 2-digit dates or modify *parts of a string*. The code in the question has some pretty obvious bugs like using the obsolete `xls` format that was replace *16 years ago* by `xlsx`. There's absolutely no reason to use `xls`. No application requires this, quite the opposite actually. `openpyxl` only works with `xlsx` files

Comment: Haven't you asked the exact same question earlier? The answer won't change if you post the same improbable claim multiple times.

Comment: `the SQL developer window` what window do you refer to? In what application?

Comment: probably excel or df => excel is doing some helpful "formatting" for you.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the code is pushing the data in xlsx format only. It was a typo

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that neither Pandas nor SQL Server nor Excel do what you claim. You haven't posted any data that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Am getting this hep everywhere that excel is doing some formatting but how to overwrite this is something I need to find.

Comment: No it doesn't. You claim so but Excel will never randomly change a *substring* in the middle of a text value. It's far more likely that the SQL queries concatenate date values as if they were strings, using different locale settings, to generate a "primary key". Something that just isn't necessary

Comment: Do these Excel files contain *formulas* that concatenate fields to generate a new value? In that case the problem is the formula ,not Excel. The formula concatenates the display text of any date fields which means the actual output depends on the styling of that Excel sheet. That's something done by the users, not by Excel itself

Comment: No Sir. The excel files are newly created during the code execution. I dont even know how to apply formula in this situation. Need to end this formatting somehow

Answer (score 0):

Closing this post, as the dataframe itself is showing date format on creation. Its not related to excel anymore. The problem lies while constructing the dataframe itself. On printing the dataframe the data appears to be formatted.
hence closing this post as the problem is very different than what was expected.

Comment: Dates both in databases and Python are binary values, they have no format. If the query returns a proper date type there won't be any formatting issues. If the query returns a string instead of a date or worse, if the table contains strings instead of actual dates, there's a very serious bug. And given the Y2K issue in those date *strings*, you won't have *any* idea what these strings mean. What does `13-07-14` mean? Is that 1900 or 2000? You can't know. Is it YY-MM-DD, YY-DD-MM, DD-MM-YY, MM-DD-YY? You can't know

Comment: okay, Thanks a lot for your reply. Checking the table datatype.